# What kind of verb tense is this? And is the grammar correct?

Tags: grammar, verbs, tenses

I always wake up earlier than most folks do. There were times when I would go to bed really late then would wake upset the next morning realizing I only slept for 4 hours.

Comment: I would use the past perfect, myself : '...I _had_ only slept ...'. 'I would wake' is the past tense and the narrative then looks further back in time.

Answer (score 2):

Verbs in both sentences in your example show the [*habitual aspect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_markers_of_habitual_aspect), i.e., used for repeated states/actions.

> I always wake up earlier than most folks do.

The [present tense](https://www.ef.com/english-resources/english-grammar/simple-present-tense/) is never used in English, except in very specific circumstances, like a live commentary, for things that are happening right now. Waking up earlier than average is a general habit or condition that repeats every morning. This use of the present tense is called the *habitual present*.

> There were times when I would go to bed really late then would wake upset the next morning realizing I only slept for 4 hours.

Repeated actions/states in the past, i.e., the [*habitual past*](https://www.thoughtco.com/habitual-past-grammar-1690829), may be marked by the use of *would + infinitive*, as in your example, *used to + infinitive*, with the implication that in the present the action/state is no longer the case, or with the simple past, especially with an adverb expressing frequency.

> When I lived in Chicago, I [*would* invariably *notice*](https://twitter.com/josh_hammer/status/986393743392739329) protesters for sundry progressive political causes.
>
> When I lived in Chicago I [*used to hit*](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowUserReviews-g35805-d2263759-r290786641-North_Avenue_Beach-Chicago_Illinois.html) the Oak St and North Ave beaches all the time with my bike. I hadn't been on North Ave beach for 20+ years before July 5, and by the looks of the beach I didn't miss anything.
>
> When I lived in Chicago and then in New York City, I [*regularly wrote*](http://www.thelittledaisybakeshop.com/blog/archives/September2016/sept3_2016.html) to my grandmother, who lived in my hometown of Portland, OR.